# Changing textbox text causes parent windows to resize incorrecly

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, resize, horizontal-scrolling

I've tried looking many places for an answer to an issue I'm having and so far I've found nothing.

What I currently have is a c# windows form with user controls inside it. Some user controls have other controls inside them. What happens when I change the text in a textbox, is its parent windows will no longer resize like they should when changing the window size. i.e. A horizontal scrollbar will appear even though horizontal scrollbars are disabled in that specific window. Its almost as if changing the text changes the parent window's styling.

In case this is too vague, I have a textbox inside a panel with a docking property set to fill. The panel has a padding of 10 in order to allow the textbox to have some white space for aesthetic purposes. This control resides within a parent control (we'll call it parent 1), which in turn resides within another control as well (we'll call it parent 2). So when I change the textbox's text (at all, even adding a space), will then make parent 2 have a horizontal scrollbar flicker and sometimes even remain when resizing the form window manually.

Comment: Please add a small code snippet that shows how you're setting this all up.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that not only the `TextBox` in the `UserControl` is docked to fill but also that the user control itself and its parent (and its parent) are Docked correctly or have anchor set so that they resize with the Form.

Do you execute any special code when the user enters a character? (`KeyPressed` event etc.). If yes you should try disabling the events temporarily to see if they cause the problem.

If you post a sample of your code it would be easier to help. Without this we can only guess, like I tried...

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue! When using autoScrollBars and double buffering, it caused the horizontal scrollbar to show when it shouldn't have (at least in my case) when resizing the window. The answer was simple, forget the autoScrollBars, and implement my own vertical scroll bar!

I was actually getting some code to post up on here for you guys to look at, but when looking at it, I decided to forget the autoscroll, and lo and behold it worked!

I'm actually curious as to why that is though. My friend heard that .net has some issues with autoScroll but I didn't think it would be to this degree.